# Error in calculating distance using latitude & longitude (PostgreSQL)

Tags: postgresql, distance, latitude-longitude

I am trying to calculate the distance between two locations given their latitude and longitude information on postgres sql.

On doing a google search, I found that I can use the following function:

---

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION gc_dist (_lat1 FLOAT8,_lon1 FLOAT8,_lat2 FLOAT8,_lon2 FLOAT8) RETURNS FLOAT8
AS
$$
SELECT ACOS(SIN($1)*SIN($3) + COS($1)*COS($3)*COS($4 - $2))*6371;$$ LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE;

---

I used this function on a couple of lat/long combinations and result seems to be throwing odd values e.g.

1) select gc_dist(34.313004, 133.86454, 34.312454, 133.86337) as dist;

Result: 8.04 KM

2) select gc_dist(34.313004, 133.86454, 34.313983,  133.83002) as dist;

Result: 213.50 KM

You can see change result from 1) & 2) are too far whereas long/lat is pretty close (checked on https://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html, Result1 should be 0.1236 and Result2: 3.172 >> which seems ok to me)

what am I doing wrong here?

Please help. I am new to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you use built in PostGIS functionality?  For example, your first distance could be calculated using:

```
select st_distancesphere(st_makepoint(34.313004, 133.86454), st_makepoint(34.312454, 133.86337));
```

Which gives the result of `136.82660446` (meters).

Comment: Thanks! I ended up using PostGIS for now.

Comment: Be sure to upvote and accept, so that people in the future can be guided the right way.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using a formula in miles instead of in kilometers.
Look, the constant is different here http://www.codecodex.com/wiki/Calculate_Distance_Between_Two_Points_on_a_Globe#PostgreSQL_PL.2FPERLU

The formula is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula

Comment: If the issue was in miles or KM, the ratio of results from two sources (site & sql) cannot be off.

Comment: There is probably another error. Different implementation in codecodex example page might help.